# How to construct a string based on UTF8?

Tags: java, unicode

I think I can use `\u****` to construct a character based on UTF16, how to construct a string using UTF8?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strings in Java are encoding-agnostic (they use UTF-16 internally, but that doesn't matter here). The codes you are entering after `\u` are Unicde *code points*, they are not the actual binary representation of characters. Each character has an associated code point. Different encodings define how you map code points to given binary represantation.

That being said you construct string using code points and then convert it to arbitrary encoding using `getBytes()` method. For example [Euro sign](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm) (`€`):

```
"\u20AC".getBytes("UTF-8");   //-30,  -126, -84
"\u20AC".getBytes("UTF-16");  //-2, -1, 32, -84
"\u20AC".getBytes("UTF-32");  // 0,  0, 32, -84
```

Worth to remember: UTF-16 isn't really using 16 bits all the time!

Comment: +1 for "Strings in Java are encoding-agnostic". 90% of all Java programmers fail to understand that.

Comment: I believe the `\uNNNN` syntax in Java actually is a UTF-16 _code-unit_. That is, writing a character outside the BMP (i.e., greater than U+FFFF) requires a pair of surrogate code points written this way (e.g., `'\uD800\uDC00'`). Some other languages like C++ treat `\uNNNN` properly as a code point (and writing a surrogate code point is illegal), and use `\UNNNNNNNN` for code points outside the BMP.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is useful but it doesn't actually say how to construct a string from UTF-8 data.

Just in case someone wants to know the answer, here it is:

```
byte[] bytes = ...; // UTF-8 bytes.
String string = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```